# .NET LINQ , List of Orders grouped by CustomerId across three tables?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, linq

I have three tables in my SQL-database

- Orders (Id, Value, Timestamp)
- Customer(Id, Firstname, Lastname)
- OrderCustomer(Id, CustomerId, OrdersId)

I want to achieve that I get a list of results where each object got a customerid and the related orders of that customer.

I have seen this example at MSDN.com, which is nearly what I need, but only with 2 tables:

```
Dim customerList = From cust In customers
               Group Join ord In orders On
               cust.CustomerID Equals ord.CustomerID
               Into CustomerOrders = Group,
                    OrderTotal = Sum(ord.Total)
               Select cust.CompanyName, cust.CustomerID,
                      CustomerOrders, OrderTotal
```

My code right now only gives me a list with all the customers and an order, but they are not grouped together.
So its like:

- Customer 1 - Order 1
- Customer 1 - Order 5
- Customer 2 - Order 2
- Customer 2 - Order 3
- Customer 2 - Order 36

  ```
  Dim results =  From Customers In db.Customers
  Join OrderCustomer In db.OrderCustomer on Customers.ID Equals OrderCustomer.CustomerId
  Group Join Orders In db_alt.Orders On OrderCustomer.orderId Equals Orders.Id
  Into CustomerOrders = Group,
  OrderTotal = Sum(aufträge.Order_Value)
  Select Customers.Firstname, Customers.Firstname, CustomerOrders, OrderTotal, Customers.ID
  ```

Comment: You can do this with only 1 query. You just need 2 joins. I suggest you 1st try in DBMS with direct query to test if you get desired output.
Query should look like:
SELECT * FROM OrderCustomer, Customer, Orders
WHERE OrderCustomer.CustomerId = Customer.Id 
AND OrderCustomer.OrdersId = OrdersId

Comment: I've updated my question with the current code I have. I don't know how to group the result to have an object with the customerId and the list of the orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your foreign keys are properly set up, LINQ to SQL or EF should see the properties and you can do your query like this:

```
     var result = db.Customers.Include("Order") // EF
```

That should bring all `customers` and each of them will have a collection of `orders`

Or        `var result = db.Customers.Select(c=>new {Customer = c, Orders = c.Orders}`